# What's the best way to accurately pinpoint errors with exceptions?

Tags: java, exception

I've read a lot about exceptions but I'm having a hard time piecing it all together... I'm trying to write a utility method for reading a file (this is for practice so I'm not interested in using a library):

```
public static List<String> readFile(String file)
        throws NoSuchFileException,
               AccessDeniedException,
               SomeException1,
               SomeException2,
               IOException {
    Path p = Paths.get(file);
    if (!Files.exists(p)) {
        throw new NoSuchFileException(file);
    } else if (!Files.isRegularFile(p)) {
        throw new SomeException1(file);
    } else if (!Files.isReadable(p)) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException(file);
    } else if (Files.size(p) == 0) {
        throw new SomeException2(file);
    }
    return Files.readAllLines(p);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println("The proper use is: java MyProgram file1.txt file2.txt");
            return;
        }

        List<List<String>> files = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            try {
                files.add(Utilities.readFile(args[i]));
            } catch (NoSuchFileException e) {
                System.out.printf("File %s does not exist%n", e.getMessage());
                System.exit(-1);
            } catch (SomeException1 e) {
                System.out.printf("File %s is not a regular file%n", e.getMessage());
                throw e;
            } catch (AccessDeniedException e) {
                System.out.printf(
                    "Access rights are insufficient to read file %s%n", e.getMessage()
                );
                throw new AccessDeniedException(e);
            } catch (SomeException2 e) {
                System.out.printf("File %s is empty%n", e.getMessage());
                throw new SomeOtherException(e);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I want to throw precise exceptions so I can catch them later and write relevant error messages for the user, but this look bad... Is there a better way to do this?

There are several problems I see, here are my thoughts:

1. I'm pretty sure this is an exceptional case, not flow control, so I should use exceptions.
2. I can't throw one general exception or I won't be able to pinpoint the cause for the error.
3. On the other hand, this feels like too many exceptions, which pollutes the method signature. Plus I can't use unchecked exceptions, as these are not programmer errors and they can be dealt with.
4. And I can't find standard exceptions that are precise enough for my use case.
5. But I'm not sure if this is the right time to create a custom type of exception or if this is the wrong way to address the problem...

Comment: The else is not needed, if the first if is true the exception will be thrown and you will not get to the rest of the method.

Comment: Is there an advantage to turning them into ifs?

Comment: They become somewhat more readable I think, though that's a matter of taste. Plus you can make them oneliners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your exceptions are all derived from a common base exception, for example `IOException`, it is sufficient to add a `throws` declaration for the base exception:

```
public static List<String> readFile(String file)
        throws IOException {
    // ...
}
```

If you don't want to create different exceptions for all cases, use the message attached to each exception:

```
public static List<String> readFile(String file)
        throws IOException {
    Path p = Paths.get(file);
    if (!Files.exists(p)) {
        throw new IOException( "No such file: " + file);
    } else if (!Files.isRegularFile(p)) {
        throw new IOException( "No regular file: " + file);
    } else if (!Files.isReadable(p)) {
        throw new IOException( "Access denied: " + file);
    } else if (Files.size(p) == 0) {
        throw new IOException( "Empty file: " + file);
    }
    return Files.readAllLines(p);
}
```

If all you need to do for error handling is to print error messages, this is a good option.

Comment: Good point for the common base exception, I didn't know that! However since IOException is a pretty generic type, I might catch other exceptions that I do not want to catch here or that have no good message to display... That's the problem I was having with general exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions can be part of object hierarchies, which lets you deal with exceptions in detail or at whatever level of abstraction you find convenient.  For example, both `FileNotFoundException` and `CharacterEncodingException` extend `IOException`.  You could choose to catch them at the abstract `IOException` level, or deal with them individually like this:

```
catch(FileNotFouncException e){
    // handle it specifically
} 
catch(CharacterEncodingException e){
    // handle it specifically
}
catch(IOException e){
    // all others handle the same way
    // (Superclass must be handled after subclasses)
}
```

You can also group exceptions that don't have a convenient common base class, merely because you want to handle them in the same way, like this:

```
catch(ZipException|ZipError e){
    // deal with corrupt zip file once, even though they come from different class hierarchies 
}
```

Comment: So would you say it's ok to handle all these exceptions specifically, except for for IOException? I feel like each error deserves its appropriate response but I was wondering if I'm going too far into the details...

Comment: That was just an example to illustrate how you can handle things at different levels of abstraction according to your needs.  Ask yourself what you would do with each exception type--do you just call `getMessage()` and respond in the same way for each?  Then use the most abstract Exception type you can.  Do you react differently to each? Use specific types.  Do you do a mixture? Handle the specific types first, then use the abstract one as a catch-all so you can fail gracefully.